# jQuery AJAX server side sends data

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, server-side

So there are tons of examples alike to invoke server methods from client side using jQuery AJAX.
Once the HTTP 1.1 connection keeps alive, the client send GET or POST request to receive the data as soon as possible. If connection is not alive, client recreates it and initiate the request. With an additional delay due to connection overhead or errors.

I'm looking for vice versa technics. In terms of C language — send() and recv() functions on server side when connection exists. Server sends data by the existing connection to the client (or all the clients connected by the time). The client catches data and updates/modifies its DOM.

Any jQuery AJAX example links, thoughts, restrictions or explanations, please.

UPD: The best option will be the simplest. Say, using CGI and jQuery methods, if possible.

Comment: Try WebSockets, maybe?

Comment: Http is stateless, so this doesn't remember the client or it's state. Client always initiates the request and then server sends the response and forgets about the client. If client doesn't get the response then it can initiate the request again.

Comment: Thank you all. That helped me figure out all that jazz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you're looking for PUSH technology!?

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29
- http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery
- http://blog.sney.net/http-push-per-ajax-long-polling-comet-programmierung/2012/06/19/
- http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwasyncwebrequest/wwasyncwebrequest.htm
- http://html5hacks.com/blog/2013/04/21/push-notifications-to-the-browser-with-server-sent-events/
- http://pusher.com/tutorials/html5_realtime_push_notifications
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket